# Unable to commit and push change to openshift online GIT repository

Tags: java, spring, openshift

I committed and push the first change to openshift online for the first time and I get an error.  The project is a java application that uses Spring 3.1 on Jbossas7 cartridge and mysql5.5.  The project was created by spring roo and uses aspectj file extensively.  Here is the error I get:

```html
Stopping jbossas cartridge
Repairing links for 1 deployments
Building git ref 'master', commit cccfbcb
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn -e clean package -Popenshift -DskipTests'
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232336; 2012-12-18 14:36:37-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.71/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Numbers 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Numbers ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) @ Numbers ---
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:test-compile (default) @ Numbers ---
[WARNING] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: net.mfjassociates.utilities.domain.Document [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
[WARNING] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: net.mfjassociates.utilities.domain.Prefix [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Numbers ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Numbers ---
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/util/GeneratorUtils.java:[133,47] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getCode()
  location: variable prefix of type Prefix
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[33,7] error: Document is not abstract and does not override abstract method setInUse(Boolean) in Generatable
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[87,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getCode()
  location: variable prefix of type Prefix
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[87,65] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getNumerical()
  location: class Document
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[99,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method entityManager()
  location: class Document
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[105,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method findAllDocuments()
  location: class Document
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[111,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method merge()
  location: class Document
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[117,19] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method findDocumentsByInUse(Boolean,String,String)
  location: class Document
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[30,7] error: Prefix is not abstract and does not override abstract method setInUse(Boolean) in Generatable
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[88,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method entityManager()
  location: class Prefix
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[96,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method findAllPrefixes()
  location: class Prefix
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[102,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method merge()
  location: class Prefix
/var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[108,19] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 13 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.492s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 17 21:49:52 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project Numbers: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/util/GeneratorUtils.java:[133,47] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getCode()
[ERROR] location: variable prefix of type Prefix
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[33,7] error: Document is not abstract and does not override abstract method setInUse(Boolean) in Generatable
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[87,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getCode()
[ERROR] location: variable prefix of type Prefix
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[87,65] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getNumerical()
[ERROR] location: class Document
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[99,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method entityManager()
[ERROR] location: class Document
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[105,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method findAllDocuments()
[ERROR] location: class Document
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[111,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method merge()
[ERROR] location: class Document
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Document.java:[117,19] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method findDocumentsByInUse(Boolean,String,String)
[ERROR] location: class Document
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[30,7] error: Prefix is not abstract and does not override abstract method setInUse(Boolean) in Generatable
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[88,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method entityManager()
[ERROR] location: class Prefix
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[96,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method findAllPrefixes()
[ERROR] location: class Prefix
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[102,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method merge()
[ERROR] location: class Prefix
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/net/mfjassociates/utilities/domain/Prefix.java:[108,19] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/543f207ce0b8cda5a1000194/jbossas

For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

Any idea what is going on or what I should do to make this work?  Do I have to do anything special in terms of building to make this working? As you will see the aspectj-maven-plugin is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the openshift deploy option from your POM? One of the error messages indicates that you did. Are you also sure that all your code is building?